# youtube live recording timestamp

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on an YTL api project and I'm been successful in starting and stopping the live streaming form a PHP application but I need to extend the project to a VOD functionality where I need to know the exact timestamp when the recorded video begun. Any hint on how to retrieve the initial timestamp of a recorded event?

Comment: What do you mean by initial timestamp?  Do you mean the date and time when the Live Event started?

Comment: I start the live event through an API call and I know the issue time of the API but the Youtube services take a while to effectively start recording the event.  The event is a debate with many speakers and my need is to create an event index and be able to jump to a specific intervention.  I know the time of single intervention (hh:mm:ss) and I need to compute the offset inside the recording to jump.